# How to get a Firebase user by its id?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In firebase you can access the current user's data by using `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()...`, I am wondering is there a way to access other Authenticated users public data by their id or email.

Answer (score 2):

Accesing user data is a dangerous operation, imagine an app that allows you to change others people user name.

So in the clients you cant, unless you duplicate the user data to the RTD or the Firestore and using rules set privacy controls.

What I think you are looking for is something like the admin sdk for auth that allows to search for users using email or uid.

You can see the docs here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

If you dont want to setup a server you can go all the way in the Firebase way; using Functions. Functions is a trusted enviroment like a server, so it can use the admin sdk for auth. You could create an onCall function for doing whatever you want.

If you want to only search users, please consider having a searchable version of the user data on any database, if you are looking for an admin type of feature then Functions onCall is what you need.

You will probably want to set admin privileges using customs claims

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

```
exports.userCreationListener = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    const admins = {
        "first@admin.com": true
    };
    const email = user.email;
    if (!admins[email]) {
        return false;
    }
    const uid = user.uid;
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {superAdmin: true}).then(
        ()=>admin.database().ref(`users/${uid}`).set(true)).catch(error=>{
        console.log("SUPER_ADMIN_UPDATE_ERROR", error);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getIdToken() instead.
    String uid = user.getUid();
}
```

Read guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: this is not what i am trying to do please read the question carefully

Comment: @CHAMCHOUN in that case if you want more flexible registration you better make your own auth process instead of provided by Firebase and in this case you can do with data what ever you want.